# Xcode 4.3 from a button in a UIWebView open the same url in safari

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am relatively new to Xcode and I have started building an app that uses `UIWebView`. To make it compliant for App Store submission, Apple prefers you use Safari. To overcome this problem I want to add a button to my `UIWebView` navigation that, when clicked, will open the same url in Safari. An example of this can be seen in the Twitter app; they have a button that opens the currently viewed `UIWebView` in a Safari window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `UIWebViewDelegate`'s method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if iWantToOpenThisURLInSafari([request URL]) {
        [UIApplication openUrl:[request URL]];
        return NO; // tell the webView to not navigate to the URL, I'm handling it
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (BOOL)iWantToOpenThisURLInSafari:(NSURL* url) [
    // you just have to fill in this method.
    return NO;
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate

EDIT: more details as requested by @PaulGraham

```
// You have a pointer to you webView somewhere
UIWebView *myWebView;

// create a class which implements the UIWebViewDelegate protocol
@interface MyUIWebViewDelegate:NSObject<UIWebViewDelegate>

// in this class' @implementation, implement the shouldStartLoad..method

@implementation
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if iWantToOpenThisURLInSafari([request URL]) {
        [UIApplication openUrl:[request URL]];
        return NO; // tell the webView to not navigate to the URL, I'm handling it
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

// then, set the webView's delegate to an instance of that class

MyUIWebViewDelegate* delegate = [[MyUIWebViewDelegate alloc] init];
webView.delegate = delegate;

// your delegate will now recieve the shouldStartLoad.. messages.
```

Comment: Prody, thanks for this, can you please give an explanation of how to implement this, i understand the code above, not sure where to use it.

Comment: Prody, thanks for this, however i am still struggling to implement, do you have an example of this in a working project, sorry may come across as being dumb, but Xcode and c are all new to me

Comment: sorry, I'm not on OSX right now, and Xcode is unavailable outside of OSX, but you have everything you need right there, you just need to put the pieces together. You should read an Objective-C tutorial if this is too hard for you. You can find tutorials on http://developer.apple.com